# Reading a file in perl and assigning variables

Tags: perl, file, variables

I am trying to read a file into perl and assign variables to each of the characters in the file. I have done this a number of times and worked quite well. But for this file I am not quite sure what is it I am doing wrong.

So the file looks like this:

```
     1   1    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.1966E+02     1   66    2    2      9  81
     2   2    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.2832E+02     1    9    3    3      9  13
     3   1    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.2538E+02     1   75    2    2     13  82
     4   2    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.1507E+02   127    1    3    3     81  82
     5   1    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.2663E+02     9   80    2    2      9  17
     6   1    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.3031E+02     9   87    2    2     13  21
     7   2    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.3065E+02     9   17    3    3     17  21
     8   1    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.3574E+02    49   10    2    2     18  50
     9   2    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.3396E+02    10   94    3    3     18  58
    10   2    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.2903E+02    66   10    3    3     50  51
    11   1    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.1711E+02    80   10    2    2     51  57
    12   2    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.2776E+02    10   18    3    3     57  58
    13   1    4 4 4    0.1000E+01  0.1000E+01  0.3448E+02    16   49    2    2     22  49
```

And here what I have been trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

open OPLINE, "<$lfile" or die "\033[31mError: Can't open $lfile\033[0m ";
my $line = <OPLINE>;
while ($line) {
     #my @fields = split(" ",$line);
        if ($line =~ /\s*(\d+)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s(\d)\s(\d)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d)\s*(\d)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)/){
        my ($Line, $Xi, $Basis1, $Basis2, $Basis3, $Deriv1, $Deriv2, $Length, $Node1, $Node2, $der1, $der2, $Element1, $Element2) = ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14);
        }

}
$line = <IPNODE>;
```

The script works up until the IF argument. It seems it can't match the expressions to the file format.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: why regex when you already have `@fields` array.

Comment: yup you're right. I don't need @fields here. I was using it before trying regex.

Comment: so what's best instead of \d+? \w+ or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tries something like this:

```
my ($discard, $Line, $Xi, $Basis1, $Basis2, $Basis3, $Deriv1, 
           $Deriv2, $Length, $Node1, $Node2, $der1, $der2, 
                                   $Element1, $Element2) = split(/\s+/, $line);
```

I've added the leading `$discard` variable, because the `split()` will treat the leading spaces as the delimiter between the first and second items.

Comment: You can use `split ' '` to ignore leading whitespace. From [`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html): "`split` emulates the default behavior of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a *literal string* composed of a single space character (such as `' '` or `"\x20"` , but not e.g. `/ /` ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were `/\s+/` ; in particular, this means that *any* contiguous whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator."

Answer (score 0):

"\d" is matching digits. You have punctuation in the decimal points, and "E" and "+": "[0-9E+.]".